# XML Namespace, can not select nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, msxml

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
    <ArrayOfFileInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  <Data> ......
```

When I leave `"xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` in the Xml, the following doesn't return any nodes:

```
CString tag = L"//Data";
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr pDataTag = pXMLDocument->selectNodes((_bstr_t)tag);
```

When I remove the attribute, everything works fine though.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select namespaced nodes in XPath you need to use the facility provided by your XPath library to bind a prefix to the relevant namespace URI, and then use that prefix when selecting nodes by name.  The MSDN documentation for the selectNodes method has [a C++ example of just this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx#snippetGroup1), the key is to set the `SelectionNamespaces` property on the document

```
pXMLDocument->setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:tmp='http://tempuri.org/'");
```

which will then allow you to use an XPath of `//tmp:Data`